# Why am I getting "ERROR: right operand of 'in' is not an object' when running a signup function in React Native and Supabase?

Tags: react-native, expo, supabase

I am trying to sign up users to Supabase in React Native (expo). Upon pressing the sign up button, I get the error:

`ERROR: [TypeError: right operand of 'in' is not an object]`

Here is my sign-up logic:

```
const handleSignUp = async () => {
        try {
            // Attempt to sign up the user using Supabase authentication
            const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp(email, password);

            // If there's an error during sign up, display an alert with the error message and return
            if (error) {
                Alert.alert(error.message);
                return;
            }

            // If sign up is successful, create a user object with necessary data
            const userObject = {
                id: user.id,
                first_name: firstName,
                posts: [],
                email: email,
            };

            // Insert the user object into the 'users' table in the Supabase database
            const { data, error: insertionError } = await supabase
                .from("users")
                .upsert([userObject], { onConflict: ["id"] });

            // If there's an error during insertion, display an alert with the error message
            if (insertionError) {
                Alert.alert(insertionError.message);
            } else {
                // If insertion is successful, navigate to the 'Feed' screen
                console.log(
                    "Data successfully inserted to users table after sign up."
                );
                navigation.navigate("Feed");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // If there's an error at any point in the process, log the error
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
```

The error only occurs when running this function, and the user does not get created in the auth.users table in supabase, suggesting it may happen early on?

Help appreciated,
Thanks